# Working around lack of Optional support in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, option-type

It's 2020 and Thymeleaf still [doesn't support `Optional`](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/672) from Java 8, released six year ago. What are the workarounds?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE with Thymeleaf. I have an object of type `Foo` that the controller provides via the model/session as `foo`. It has a method `findName()` that returns `Optional<String>`. So I can put this in my template:

```html
[[${foo.findName()}]]
```

Assuming the name is `"bar"`, that shows:

> `Optional[bar]`

That works, but obviously it's not what I want.

So I tried what I would do in Java. The following should print simply the name (e.g. `foo`), or `_____` if the name is missing:

```html
[[${foo.findName().orElse("_____")}]]
```

Unfortunately that produces an exception:

> `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: ""`

Trying to use conditions, this will provide the value if it is present:

```html
[[${foo.findName().isPresent()} ? ${foo.findName().get()}]]
```

But for some reason this throws an exception:

```html
[[${foo.findName().isPresent()} ? ${foo.findName().get()} : '_____']]
```

First, I'm not sure why the example using `orElse()` doesn't work, as the `Optional` instance is an object like any of the others. Secondly, does anyone know a workaround? Thirdly, does anyone know of a workaround that is concise and doesn't take up three times the code?

(What we really need is native support in Thymeleaf so that `${foo.findName()} ?: '_____'` will just work naturally.)

Comment: Just an observation, which may help to simplify your expressions (but only slightly): Thymeleaf will throw an error when it processes 4 or more underscores in a row, in a string literal. So, for example, instead of using `'_____'` (5 underscores in a row), you can use `'\_\_\_\__'`. I have [asked a question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64307689/underscores-in-thymeleaf-text-literals). This does not relate to or help with how to handle optionals in Thymeleaf.

Comment: Yeah, as pointed out `[[${foo.findName().orElse("_____")}]]` is throwing an error not because .orElse doesn't work, but because the String `__` has special meaning.   You need to escape it.

Answer (score 3):

Since Thymeleaf uses Spring Epression language while integrated with Spring, the Thymeleaf itself is not to blame. As of the current version of Spring, the SpEl doesn't support Java 8 Optional yet, here is the GitHub issue [#20433](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20433).

Possible workarounds require different expressions:

- When you have a default value (the `_` escaping issue is resolved throught a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306235/working-around-lack-of-optional-support-in-thymeleaf/64349869#comment113715188_64306235))

  ```
  <span th:text="${foo.findName().orElse('---')" />
  ```
- When you don't want to render an enpty (or default) line, you can hide it using `th:if`:

  ```
  <th:block th:if="${foo.findName().isPresent()}">
      <span th:text="${foo.findName().get()" /> 
  </th:block>`
  ```

Comment: Thymeleaf does *not* necessarily uses spel in Spring. You can very much use ONGL and Spring.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can get to work so far is this:

```html
<th:block th:switch="${foo.findName().isPresent()}">
  <th:block th:case="true">[[${foo.findName.get()}]]</th:block>
  <th:block th:case="*">_____</th:block>
</th:block>
```

Horrors—so verbose! Is that the best that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

As **workaround for the Java Optionals funcionality** use the "Elvis Operator" and the "Safe Navigation Operator" of SpringEL:

**Safe Navigation Operator**:
If myOptional is null, this will return null instead of an error:

```
myOptional.orElse(null)?.myProperty
```

That's equivalent to this in Java:

```
myOptional.map(ObjectType::getMyProperty).orElse(null);
```

**Elvis Operator**:
If myOptional or myProperty is null, this will return "alternativeContent":

```
myOptional.orElse(null)?.myProperty?:"alternativeContent"
```

That's equivalent to this in Java:

```
myOptional.map(ObjectType::getMyProperty).orElse("alternativeContent");
```

**Easier might be, not to pass Optionals to Thymeleaf alltogether and only use the Operators mentioned above**:

```
myObject?.myProperty
myObject?.myProperty?:"alternativeContent"
```