# Underscores in Thymeleaf Text Literals

Tags: thymeleaf

**Question: How to escape multiple consecutive underscores in text literals?**

I am using the standard Thymeleaf dialect for HTML (I am **not** using Spring or SpEL here).

In Thymeleaf, I can create an underscore as a [text literal](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#text-literals) as follows:

```
<div th:text="'_'"></div>
```

This renders as:

```
<div>_</div>
```

I can create literals with 2 and 3 underscores in the same way:

```
<div th:text="'__'"></div>
<div th:text="'___'"></div>
```

But for 4 underscores, I get an error:

> *org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: ""*

I assume (***maybe incorrectly***) this is because two pairs of underscores (`__` followed by `__`) are the markers used by Thymeleaf for the [expression preprocessor](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#preprocessing). And when these are removed, I am left with an empty expression - hence the error.

I can escape the underscores using the backslash (`\`) escape character. The following all give the required results:

```
<div th:text="'\_\___'"></div>
<div th:text="'\_\_\_\__'"></div>
<div th:text="'\_\_\_\___'"></div>
<div th:text="'_\_\_\_\___'"></div>
<div th:text="'\_\_\_\_\_\___'"></div>
```

But I can't just escape *every* underscore.

This displays a stray backslash:

```
<div th:text="'\_\_\_\_\_'"></div>
```

The result is:

```
<div>____\_</div>
```

So:

1. What are the rules for escaping underscores in text literals?
2. Is it really the preprocessor which is causing this behavior (*inside text literals*) - or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this is definitely part of the preprocessor.

[It looks to me](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/bb2fd0e9005f8aab0de0a3f9f3897edea8084b88/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/standard/expression/StandardExpressionPreprocessor.java#L113) like the preprocessor only replaces an exact match of `\_\_` with `__`.  In any case where you have an odd number of `\_`'s, you will get the output `\_` -- because it's not treating `\_` as a real escape and instead only looking for `\_\_`.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon the same issue while providing underscore as placeholder for a code input field and found the following workarounds:

**1. Insert zero width space as seperator**

In the first example ('*​_​_​_​_​*') the zero witdh space is unescaped, but you can copy paste the string into your IDE of choice.

```html
<div th:text="${'_​_​_​_​_​_'}"></div>
<div th:text="${'_&#8203;_&#8203;_&#8203;_&#8203;_&#8203;_'}"></div>
<div th:text="${'_&#x200B;_&#x200B;_&#x200B;_&#x200B;_&#x200B;_'}"></div>
<div th:text="${'_&ZeroWidthSpace;_&ZeroWidthSpace;_&ZeroWidthSpace;_&ZeroWidthSpace;_&ZeroWidthSpace;_'}"></div>
```

**2. Use string replace**

Surprisingly, this also seems to work. You can use any character, but no underscores in the original string, I chose "......". You can also use it with a string of unknown length by specifying a variable instead of a fixed string.

```html
<div th:text="${#strings.replace('......', '.', '_')}"></div>
<div th:text="${#strings.replace('......', '.', '&#95;')}"></div>
```